# Use e.target.id to match target and children

Tags: jquery

I have a script that toggles a sub-menu when a target (#dave) is clicked by adding a class (.settings-active) to a parent (.bob).

The .settings-active class should also be removed by clicking anywhere outside of the target and it's children.

The issue I am having is that when the target is clicked it shows a submenu (.dd) but when I try to click a submenu item (.one,.two) the submenu disappears due to the else statement firing.

My question is twofold:

1. Can I set the target to look for a class (.dave) rather than an id like it is currently doing.
2. How can I get the submenu to remain open when a submenu item is clicked

Thank you in advance

```js
$('html').click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'dave') {
    $('.bob').toggleClass('settings-active');
  } else {
    $('.bob').removeClass('settings-active');
  }
});
```

```css
.settings-active {
  color: red;
}
.dd {
  display: none;
}
.settings-active .dd {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bob">

  <div id="dave">
    Target
    <div class="dd">
      <div class="one">one</div>
      <div class="two">two</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the `id` to attach the `click` event instead of `html`:

```
$('.dave').click(function(e) {  
    $('.bob').toggleClass('settings-active');
});
```

You can use `.stopPropagation()` to prevent submenu from disappearing:

```
$('.dave').click(function (e) {
    $('.bob').toggleClass('settings-active');
});

$('.dd div').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('clicked on: ' + $(this).html());
});

$('body').click(function (e) {    
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("dave")) {
        $('.bob').removeClass('settings-active');
    }
});
```

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/xk8ntmyh/2/

Comment: Hi erkaner, thanks for your reply, I've edited my question above as I forgot to mention that the .setings-active class should also be removed when you click anywhere but the target or its children.